# How to find objects that are in several arrays using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have five arrays that can contain the same value across them.

```
var arr1 = ['1','2','3','4'];
var arr2 = ['1','3']
var arr3 = ['1','2','3']
var arr4 = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var arr5 = ['1','3','4']
```

How can I find all of the numbers that are in all of the arrays using jQuery?

The numbers `1` and `3` are in all of the arrays?

Comment: Are your arrays sorted?

Comment: You mean like [array intersection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885557/simplest-code-for-array-intersection-in-javascript)?

Comment: @Ankit The arrays are not sorted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out

### Filtering array by duplicate elements

JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nWjcp/87/

```
var arr1 = ['1','2','3','4'];
var arr2 = ['1','3']
var arr3 = ['1','2','3']
var arr4 = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var arr5 = ['1','3','4']

var arrays = [
   arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4,arr5
    ];


var result = arrays.shift().filter(function(v) { // Filtering
    return arrays.every(function(a) {       // Seek duplicate
        return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;    
    });
});




   alert( JSON.stringify(result,null,4) ); // ['1','3']
```

Comment: This is the better way to go.

Comment: Why the null and 4  ? To make things  harder to understand ? does it contribute something to the answer ? not to mention that  every+filter+indexOf are all need polyfills

Comment: @RoyiNamir Only if you need to support IE8, in which case you need a polyfill for pretty much everything.

Answer (score 2):

First off, let's make a more manageable dataset:

```
var arrays = [
    ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    ['1', '3'],
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
    ['1', '3', '4']
];
```

Then we'll want to get all the unique elements:

```
var elements = [].concat.apply([], arrays).filter(function(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}); //["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

And then finally, check this set against each of our arrays, keeping only the elements that are present in all of them:

```
var out = elements.filter(function(item) {
    return arrays.reduce(function(present, array) {
        present = present && (array.indexOf(item) !== -1);
        return present;
    }, true);
}); //["1", "3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the usage of methods without crossbrowser support :

Here is a simple solution without "extra" non-jquery-included functions (`every` , `inArray`,`filter`(array)):

```
var arr1 = ['1','2','3','4'];
var arr2 = ['1','3']
var arr3 = ['1','2','3']
var arr4 = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var arr5 = ['1','3','4']

var arrs = [arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4,arr5];

var obj={};

$.each(arrs,function (i,arr){
     $.each(arr,function (j,n){
      obj[n]=(+obj[n] || 0) + 1;
     });
});


for (item in obj) 
{  
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(item ) && obj[item]==arrs.length) console.log(item) //1,3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find a long solution here. At first, let us find the array with least items so that search can be optimized:

```js
var arr1 = ['1','2','3','4'];
var arr2 = ['1','3', '8'];
var arr3 = ['1','2','3'];
var arr4 = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
var arr5 = ['1','3','4'];

var arrayOfArray = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5];
var arrayWithMin = null;
var outputArray = [];
$.each(arrayOfArray, function(index, arrayItem) {
    arrayWithMin = (arrayWithMin == null) ? arrayItem : (arrayWithMin.length > arrayItem.length ? arrayItem : arrayWithMin);
});

$.each(arrayWithMin, function(i, searchItem) {
    if($.inArray(searchItem, arr1) > -1 
       && $.inArray(searchItem, arr2) > -1 
       && $.inArray(searchItem, arr3) > -1 
       && $.inArray(searchItem, arr4) > -1
       && $.inArray(searchItem, arr5) > -1) {
        outputArray.push(searchItem);
    }
});

document.write(outputArray.join(', '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```